# Angular how to insert 1 data of a interface

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

```
export interface _ProjectBudgetHistories {
  createdBy?: string ;
  id?: number;
  budgetYear? : number ;
  logicalFrameworkId? : number  ;
  projectId?: number ;
  amount?: number ;
  mooe?: number ;
  co?: number;
}

pbHistories : _ProjectBudgetHistories;
let co =500;
let mooe =1000;

this.pbHistories.co = co;
this.pbHistories.mooe = mooe;

console.log(this.pbHistories);
```

this is the error  TypeError: Cannot set property 'co' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot set property 'mooe' of undefined

===>> how to update the mooe and co  only ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your property

```
pbHistories : _ProjectBudgetHistories = {};
```

Comment: thanks bro it working . this really helps me.  but why do i have to initialize the property sorry im newbie on it

Comment: @blueelite When you say `pbHistories: _ProjectBudgetHistories`, you have just declared property `pbHistories` in your class. If you would log it, you will see it will print as `undefined`. This means its value is `undefined` Now when you do `his.pbHistories.co = co;` You are adding a property `co` to `undefined`. This is "invalid", `pbHistories` has got to be an object so that I can add values to it. Also, if it helps, can you also accept the answer? :P https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: thanks i can accept it . sorry for questioning bro. but thanks for it this really helps . and for thanks for the information. :)

Comment: @blueelite No problem :)